# Connect AnyLogic to localhost SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2016, anylogic

I am trying to connect to my local SQL DB through AnyLogic 7.3.6. I have SQL Server 2016 Developer installed and the DB is in mixed authentication (Windows & SQL). When adding the connection it gives the following error:

> Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
>
> Connection refused: connect

My host is called `localhost`. I have tried leaving Login and Password blank, hoping for Windows Authentication, and I've tried adding a SQL user (Test, test) to the server, both to the same result. I am using the `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQL.ServerDriver` JDBC driver, but have also tried `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` (same result).

Can anyone explain how I can make a connection between AnyLogic 7 and SQL Server 2016 (Developer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the Windows Authentication will work with AnyLogic. So make sure to have a correct configured SQL User to use.

Make sure that "Allow remote connections to this server" is enabled. **Open SQL Server Management Studio** -> **Right click on your instance** -> **Properties** -> **Connections**.

Check so TCP/IP connections are enabled. **Open SQL Server Configuration Manager** -> **SQL Server Network Confinguration** -> **Select your instance** -> **Enable TCP/IP**. It's also possible to change the default port here.

The TCP/IP connection is using port **1433** as default. Make sure to **allow** connections through this port in your firewall.

Comment: In support of this, you can also connect to AnyLogic via a nonstandard SQL Server port. Just use SERVERNAME:PORT, eg. localhost:1115